# JavaScript - Taking user input and using in calculation to validate value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that allows users to 'refuel' by filling out a form where they can input the amount of fuel to add, however the maximum fuel amount is 180 litres, so if the existing fuel is 170 litres (the existing fuel value will be retrieved from a database), and the user tries to add 20 litres, it should produce an error. I've got some code already, but it's not producing the error. If anyone could point out the issue it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#fuel').blur(function() {
    if (!ValidateFuel()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $('#auth_form8').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!ValidateFuel()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});

function ValidateFuel() {
  var IsValid = false;
  var fuel_to_add = $('#fuel').val();
  var current_fuel = '100'; // this value will be retrieved from database
  var fuel_once_added = Number(current_fuel) + Number(fuel_to_add);

  if (fuel_once_added > 180) {
    $('#alertInvalidFuel').show();
    IsValid = false;
  } else {
    $('#alertInvalidFuel').hide();
    IsValid = true;
  }

  return IsValid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-success" role="button" data-target="#confirm-refuelG-EEGU" data-toggle="modal"><em class='fa fa-plus'></em></a>

<div id="confirm-refuelG-EEGU" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Fuel G-EEGU</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="auth_form8" id="auth_form8" method="post" action="action_refuel.php">
          <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
          <hr>
          <input class="form-control" id="aircraft_id" name="aircraft_id" value='1' type="hidden">
          <div class="form-group" name="fuel" id="fuel">
            <label for="auth_code8" class="control-label">
                  Fuel to add:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="fuel" name="fuel" type="number" required>
          </div>
          <div style="display:none;" class="alert alert-danger" id="alertInvalidFuel">
            <p>Fuel will exceed 180 litres.</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code8" id="auth_code8">
            <label for="auth_code8" class="control-label">
                  Authorisation Code</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input8" autocomplete="new-password" name="refuel_auth_code" type="password" required>
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon" id="iconBad8"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Fuel</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/82jd2oes/)**

Comment: `e` is undefined. It should be `$('#fuel').blur(function(e) {
    if (!ValidateFuel()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: @Xufox This does not solve the issue unfortunately. No errors showing on JSHint or console. I think it's just not triggering the validate function?

Comment: What @Xufox said, and your html is not formatted well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<div class="form-group" name="fuel" id="fuel">
    <label for="auth_code8" class="control-label">Fuel to add:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="fuel" name="fuel" type="number" required>
</div>
```

Your div has `id="fuel"` and so does the `input`. Remove the `id` from the `div` or make it unique. Also, there is no name attribute for `div` elements, you should remove that as well.